# Type Error Converting circular structure to JSON starting at object with constructor 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

the problem I have is that I want a Medico from the collection to be updated in the collection and I managed to unstructure the data of the Medico name and email

and I managed to get the ID of the assigned hospital

and when I modify them I can't get it to send them to me in the correct format. I attach the code that I have

```
  cargarMedico(id: string) {
    if (id === 'nuevo') {
      return;
    } else {

      this.medicoService.obtenerMedicoPorId(id)
        .subscribe(medico => {

          //Regla de validacion
          if (!medico) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medicos/`)
          }

          console.log(medico)
          const hospital = medico.hospital?._id;
          console.log(hospital)

          const { nombre, email } = medico;
          console.log(nombre, email, hospital)
          this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
          this.medicoForm.setValue({ nombre, email, hospital });
        });
    }
  }
```

Here I perform the destructuring to get the necessary data

```
guardarMedico() {

    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value

    if (this.medicoSeleccionado) {
      //actualizar
      const data = {
        ...this.medicoForm,
        _id: this.medicoSeleccionado.hospital
      }
      this.medicoService.actualizarMedico(data)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Actualizado', `${nombre} actualizado correctamente`, 'success');

        })

    } else {
      //crear
      const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
      console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
      this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
        .subscribe((resp: any) => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
          this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.medico._id}`)
        })
    }


  }
```

This is where I save for recording in the collection

```
  public medicoSeleccionado: Medico | any;
```

```
export class Medico {

    constructor(
        public nombre: string,
        public img: string,
        public email: string,
        public _id: string,
        public usuario?: _MedicoUser,
        public hospital?: Hospital

    ) { }
}
```

this is the Model of Medico

And this is the bug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZIQV.png)

If you need more part of the code to help me solve the problem, ask for it

I had problems destructuring the hospital since I tried to do it directly but it gave me an error and of course I necessarily need that ID to update the Medico

```
const { nombre, email, hospital{ _id} } = medico;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all your destructuring is wrong, you should do something like this:

```
const { nombre, email, hospital } = medico;
const { _id } = hospital;
```

and maybe put an alias to the `_id` but that's up to you.

now your save method should take the value of form not the instance which is what you do by just doing `...this.form`, it should be `...this.form.value`

```
guardarMedico() {

    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value

    if (this.medicoSeleccionado) {
      //actualizar
      const data = {
        ...this.medicoForm.value,
        _id: this.medicoSeleccionado.hospital._id
      }
      this.medicoService.actualizarMedico(data)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Actualizado', `${nombre} actualizado correctamente`, 'success');

        })

    } else {
      //crear
      const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
      console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
      this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
        .subscribe((resp: any) => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
          this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.medico._id}`)
        })
    }


  }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. When making the changes, I don't know if I implemented them correctly, but I understand what you wanted to do, the problem arose along this line.


          const { nombre, email, hospital } = medico;
          const { _id } = hospital;
          console.log(nombre, email, _id)
          this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
         >> this.medicoForm.setValue({ nombre, email, hospital }); <<

since the complete object is entered there and if I try to enter only the id it gives me an error

Comment: ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/medicos/63731b2f6db9b36449225a35', ok: false, …}error: {ok: true, msg: 'Medico no encontrado'}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/medicos/63731b2f6db9b36449225a35: 400 Bad Request"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 400statusText: "Bad Request"url: "http://localhost:3000/api/medicos/63731b2f6db9b36449225a35"[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase

Comment: And in the browser network it tells me an error that I put in the try Cacht

"medico not found"